# Visual Basic Compile Error - Invalid Character

Tags: vba, outlook

I got a [VB SCRIPT](http://techniclee.wordpress.com/2010/12/16/new-mail-notification-for-an-additional-mailbox/) off the internet to create **new mail alerts for secondary email accounts** in Outlook(2010).

Now this is the first part of the code, and when running Outlook, it gives me the following error:

"Compile Error: Invalid Character"

**The debugger underlines the _ character in the following line:   "sndPlaySoundA" _**

```
'On the next line change the file name and path of the sound you want to play.'
Public Const SOUND_TO_PLAY = "C:\Windows\Media\Speech On.wav"
Public Const SND_ASYNC = &H1

Public Declare Function sndPlaySound Lib "winmm.dll" Alias "sndPlaySoundA" _ 
(ByVal lpszSoundName As String, ByVal uFlags As Long) As Long Public Declare Function    MessageBox _
    Lib "User32" Alias "MessageBoxA" _
        (ByVal hWnd As Long, _
        ByVal lpText As String, _
        ByVal lpCaption As String, _
        ByVal wType As Long) _
    As Long


Function OpenOutlookFolder(strFolderPath As String) As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    ' Purpose: Opens an Outlook folder from a folder path.'
    ' Written: 4/24/2009'
    ' Author:  BlueDevilFan'
    ' Outlook: All versions'
    Dim arrFolders As Variant, _
        varFolder As Variant, _
        bolBeyondRoot As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    If strFolderPath = "" Then
        Set OpenOutlookFolder = Nothing
    Else
        Do While Left(strFolderPath, 1) = "\"
            strFolderPath = Right(strFolderPath, Len(strFolderPath) - 1)
        Loop
        arrFolders = Split(strFolderPath, "\")
        For Each varFolder In arrFolders
            Select Case bolBeyondRoot
                Case False
                    Set OpenOutlookFolder = Outlook.Session.Folders(varFolder)
                    bolBeyondRoot = True
                Case True
                    Set OpenOutlookFolder = OpenOutlookFolder.Folders(varFolder)
            End Select
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                Set OpenOutlookFolder = Nothing
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

**UPDATE:** A new error has risen: (After I fixed the New line issue on line 1 after "sndPlaySoundA") as refered to by Adrian below)

"Compile Error Expected: End of statement" and the following word is highlighted: "Public"

**UPDATE2**: Next error:

Compile Error: User defined type not defined(For "Mailbox - supportdesk\Inbox")

```
Dim objFM1 As FolderMonitor

Private Sub Application_Quit()
    Set objFM1 = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set objFM1 = New FolderMonitor
    'Edit the folder path on the next line as needed.'
    objFM1.FolderToWatch OpenOutlookFolder("Mailbox - supportdesk\Inbox")
    End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with FolderMonitor.  Is it an in-built Outlook class or a separate library?  If it's separate, have you added a reference to it under Tools>References?

Comment: no I don't think I did...Will see what I can do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the code sample you've provided there you need a new line immediately after the `_`.  The underscore character is a line continuation in VBA (which is what you're using, not VBScript.  Slightly different beasts) and so requires that you continue on the next line, not the same line.  So instead of

```
Public Declare Function sndPlaySound Lib "winmm.dll" Alias "sndPlaySoundA" _ (ByVal lpszSoundName As String, ByVal uFlags As Long) As Long Public Declare Function MessageBox _
Lib "User32" Alias "MessageBoxA" _
    (ByVal hWnd As Long, _
    ByVal lpText As String, _
    ByVal lpCaption As String, _
    ByVal wType As Long) _
As Long
```

you should have

```
Public Declare Function sndPlaySound Lib "winmm.dll" Alias "sndPlaySoundA" _ 
(ByVal lpszSoundName As String, ByVal uFlags As Long) As Long 

Public Declare Function MessageBox _
Lib "User32" Alias "MessageBoxA" _
    (ByVal hWnd As Long, _
    ByVal lpText As String, _
    ByVal lpCaption As String, _
    ByVal wType As Long) _
As Long
```

**EDIT**: I obviously didn't read all the way to the end of that example line, or else I would have seen that the example somehow managed to mash two function declarations onto one line as well as using the invalid positioning of the line separator.  I've fixed that up now.

Comment: Cool thank you. But now another error arised: "Compile Error  Expected: End of statement" and the following word is highlighted: "Public" ...In the second line(...As Long Public...)

Comment: @DextrousDave Okay, I've edited the answer to fix that.  Duh.  I really should have read to the end of that line.

Comment: thank you. It seems like all the errors are now fixed except for one, but it is not syntax: It says: "User defined type not defined" for the following line: objFM1.FolderToWatch OpenOutlookFolder("Mailbox - supportdesk\Inbox")

Comment: That would be in a section of code not included in your example above?  Can you also include that code in your original post so we can have a look at it as well?

Comment: but thank you for your help, you did answer my question...the rest was just bonus